# Bootstrap navbar collapses fine but won't display on larger screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

My code was working fine, but I decided to add a hamburger button, and now I have an issue.

The button works fine, but when my screen is larger than the breakpoint, I have no navigation showing on my screen. I'm sure it is a matter of missing a tag or something, but I can't see it and could use some help. I have jQuery and Bootstrap 3 and CSS loaded.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-
toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsemenu" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="src-only">Menu</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LORI</a>
     </div>
<div class="collapse navbar collapse" id="collapsemenu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
   </div>       

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. this code works

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lori</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```